# How to lookup multiple cells in an array and put them in one cell, using multiple criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with data, extracted from a few lists, which then outputs a line of text that I want to use.
It looks a bit like this:

| Day | Shift | Code | Condition | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | Early | 123ABC | External | Mon 2pm |
| Monday | Night | 631XYZ | (Blank) | (Blank) |
| Tuesday | Early | 518DZA | Internal 1 | Tue 631-518 |
| Tuesday | Late | 321POI | Internal 2 | TUE 518-321 |
| Tuesday | Night | 321POI | (Blank) | (Blank) |
| Thursday | Night | 518DZA | External | Wed 6am |
| Friday | Early | 462YNO | Internal 1 | Fri 518-462 |
| Friday | Late | 731EXM | Internal 1 | Fri 462-731 |

The desired result would be something like this:

| (Blank) | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| External | 2pm | (Blank) | 6am | (Blank) | (Blank) |
| Internal 1 | (Blank) | Change 631-518 | (Blank) | (Blank) | Change 518-462-731 |
| Internal 2 | (Blank) | Change 518-321 -condition change- | (Blank) | (Blank) | (Blank) |

(In words: The output column of table 1 should be put in a row in table 2, depending on the condition column of table 1)

All the data in table 1 is automated and should be fine.

---

My current approach uses a quite nested formula, which works, as long as there's no doubles (like on Friday, internal 1).
This is what it looks like, for the 'Internal 1' Row in table 2:

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(IF("Condition Column="Internal 1";UNIQUE("Change" & CHAR(10) & 
TEXTJOIN ("-";TRUE;RIGHT('Output Column';7);LEFT('Output Column';3)="Mon")))));"");
(('Condition Column'="Internal 1")*(LEFT('Output Column';3)="Mon")));"")
```

"Internal 1" and "Mon" are dynamic cells, that refer to External/Internal 1/Internal 2; and the 3day codes for the respective dates.

As stated, this works, as long as there's no doubles in the condition, on the same day. So up until Thursday it works all good, but Friday gives me an overflow/spill error.
I can't simply add 2 empty rows below each used row.

I have been working on this problem for a bit now, and this is the closest I've gotten.

Additional notes: I'd rather not use VBA; Excel is not natively in English on my system, so there might be a translation error or brackets error in the formula, should someone try to copy it.
Also, both tables are not formatted as tables, but just raw data/arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you could try provided you have access to `MS365`:

The following formula is bit lengthy, since I have tried to sort the day, so irrespective of any position of day in the actual source it will sort up accordingly, also one should note since `TEXTJOIN()` functions has character limitations then this may return a `#CALC!` error after the limit has crossed, but if its within then you are good to go with it.

---

### [image]

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G11</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _data, A2:E9,
     _condition, INDEX(_data,,4),
     _output, TEXTAFTER(TAKE(_data,,-1)," "),
     _day, TEXTAFTER(SORT(VLOOKUP(TAKE(_data,,1),{"Monday","1.Monday";"Tuesday","2.Tuesday";"Wednesday","3.Wednesday";"Thursday","4.Thursday";"Friday","5.Friday"},2,0)),"."),
     _unicon, UNIQUE(TOCOL(_condition,1)),
     _uniday, TOROW(UNIQUE(_day)),
     _rows, ROWS(_unicon),
     _cols, COLUMNS(_uniday),
     _databody, MAKEARRAY(_rows,_cols,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(_output,(INDEX(_uniday,c)=_day)*(INDEX(_unicon,r)=_condition),"")),1))),
     VSTACK(HSTACK("",_uniday),HSTACK(_unicon,IFERROR(IF(--TEXTSPLIT(_databody,"-"),"Change "&CHAR(10)&_databody, ""),_databody))))
```

---

**Edit:**

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _data, B3:L16,
     _removenulls, FILTER(_data,TAKE(_data,,1)<>""),
     _condition, INDEX(_removenulls,,10),
     _output, TEXTAFTER(TAKE(_removenulls,,-1)," ",,,,TAKE(_removenulls,,-1)),
     _day, TEXTAFTER(SORT(VLOOKUP(TAKE(_removenulls,,1),{"Ma","1.Ma";"Di","2.D1";"Wo","3.Wo";"Do","4.Do";"Vr","5.Vr"},2,0)),"."),
     _unicon, UNIQUE(TOCOL(_condition,1)),
     _uniday, TOROW(UNIQUE(_day)),
     _rows, ROWS(_unicon),
     _cols, COLUMNS(_uniday),
     _databody, MAKEARRAY(_rows,_cols,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(_output,(INDEX(_uniday,c)=_day)*(INDEX(_unicon,r)=_condition),"")),1))),
     VSTACK(HSTACK("",_uniday),HSTACK(_unicon,IFERROR(IF(--LEFT(TEXTAFTER(_databody," ")),"Change "&CHAR(10)&_databody,""),_databody))))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the LET function you can try this. The formula is in cell I12 and filled across range I12:M14.

```
 =LET(result,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(" ",,RIGHT(FILTER($E$2:$E$9, 
 ($H12&"|"&I$11=$D$2:$D$9&"|"&$A$2:$A$9)),
 LEN(FILTER($E$2:$E$9,($H12&"|"&I$11=$D$2:$D$9&"|"&$A$2:$A$9)))-
 FIND("",FILTER($E$2:$E$9,($H12&"|"&I$11=$D$2:$D$9&"|"&$A$2:$A$9))))),""),
 IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Internal",$H12)),LEN(result)>0),"Change 
 ","")&result)
```

[image: How to lookup multiple cells in an array and put them in one cell, using multiple criteria?]

Or without LET.

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Internal",$H12)),LEN(IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(" 
",,RIGHT(FILTER($E$2:$E$9, 
($H12&"|"&I$11=$D$2:$D$9&"|"&$A$2:$A$9)),LEN(FILTER($E$2:$E$9, 
($H12&"|"&I$11=$D$2:$D$9&"|"&$A$2:$A$9)))-FIND(" ",FILTER($E$2:$E$9, 
($H12&"|"&I$11=$D$2:$D$9&"|"&$A$2:$A$9))))),""))>0),"Change 
","")&IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(" ",,RIGHT(FILTER($E$2:$E$9, 
($H12&"|"&I$11=$D$2:$D$9&"|"&$A$2:$A$9)),LEN(FILTER($E$2:$E$9, 
($H12&"|"&I$11=$D$2:$D$9&"|"&$A$2:$A$9)))-FIND(" ",FILTER($E$2:$E$9, 
($H12&"|"&I$11=$D$2:$D$9&"|"&$A$2:$A$9))))),"")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try it out as well! Just wondering, as I'm somewhat starting to understand the LET function, is it possible to name this part aswell "$E$2:$E$9, 
 ($H12&"|"&I$11=$D$2:$D$9&"|"&$A$2:$A$9)" because it seems to be just repeating as well. Also, I'm not sure what the SEARCH("Internal";$H12) is supposed to do/find. Thanks again!

Comment: =LET(filtermatrix,$E$2:$E$9,filterinclude,($H12&"|"&I$11=$D$2:$D$9&"|"&$A$2:$A$9),result,IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(" ",,RIGHT(FILTER(filtermatrix,filterinclude),LEN(FILTER(filtermatrix,filterinclude))-FIND(" ",FILTER(filtermatrix,filterinclude)))),""),IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Internal",$H12)),LEN(result)>0),"Change ","")&result) The filter matrix and the filter include argument can be named as shown in the above formula. ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Internal",$H12)) checks if "Internal" is found in range H12:H14. If it is found the word "Change" is added to the results like in range I13:M14.