# Formula breaks/fails when encountering '-0'

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Okay so building on my [Previous Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78040623/how-to-lookup-multiple-cells-in-an-array-and-put-them-in-one-cell-using-multipl) the formula works as a charm, for which thanks for the help. Until it runs into a '-0X'.

So quick summary:

I have an output table, which needs to be sorted into another table.
The output column of this first table displays either "day - hour" or "day YYY-XXX" (x and y can both be letters or numbers) or remains empty ("" is returned).

This is the code used (slightly adapted to my own language).

```
=LET(
     _data, B3:L16,
     _removenulls, FILTER(_data,TAKE(_data,,1)<>""),
     _condition, INDEX(_removenulls,,9),
     _output, TEXTAFTER(TAKE(_removenulls,,-1)," ",,,,TAKE(_removenulls,,-1)),
     _day, TEXTAFTER(SORT(VLOOKUP(TAKE(_removenulls,,1),{"Ma","1.Ma";"Di","2.D1";"Wo","3.Wo";"Do","4.Do";"Vr","5.Vr"},2,0)),"."),
     _unicon, UNIQUE(TOCOL(_condition,1)),
     _uniday, {"Ma"\"Di"\"Wo"\"Do"\"Vr"\"Za"},
     _rows, ROWS(_unicon),
     _cols, COLUMNS(_uniday),
     _databody, MAKEARRAY(_rows,_cols,LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,FILTER(_output,(INDEX(_uniday,c)=_day)*(INDEX(_unicon,r)=_condition),"")),1))),
     _Calc;VSTACK(HSTACK("",_uniday),HSTACK(_unicon,IFERROR(IF(--LEFT(TEXTAFTER(_databody,"-")),"Change "&CHAR(10)&_databody,""),_databody)));
     _Calc)
```

**
Now for the current problem:**

Whenever the code encounters -0XX it breaks that cell on the output table, that is, it's just not displayed.

When I change the '-' to another character, it shows, but will drop the added 'change'; I was able to determine that the issue lies within the '_Calc' part of the formula, (as '_Databody' still returns the value). When I drop the double unary, it also works, but still drops the added 'change'.

However, I cannot think of a solution.

**So current start and result:**

| Day | Shift | Code | Condition | Output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Monday | Early | 123ABC | External | Mon 2pm |
| Monday | Night | 631XYZ |  |  |
| Tuesday | Early | 0XPDZA | Internal 1 | Tue 631-0XP |
| Tuesday | Late | 321POI | Internal 2 | Tue 518-321 |

Desired result:

| (Blank) | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| External | 2pm |  |  |  |  |  |
| Internal 1 |  | Change 631-0XP |  |  |  |  |
| Internal 2 |  | Change 518-321 |  |  |  |  |

Actual result:

Without modifications

| (Blank) | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| External | 2pm |  |  |  |  |  |
| Internal 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Internal 2 |  | Change 518-321 |  |  |  |  |

With modifications (removing the double unary)

| (Blank) | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| External | 2pm |  |  |  |  |  |
| Internal 1 |  | 631-0XP |  |  |  |  |
| Internal 2 |  | 518-321 |  |  |  |  |

With modifications (putting '--' instead of '-' between outputs, not editing the formula)

| (Blank) | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| External | 2pm |  |  |  |  |  |
| Internal 1 |  | 631--0XP |  |  |  |  |
| Internal 2 |  | 518--321 |  |  |  |  |

Additional info:
I hope this is clear enough, the actual data is a bit larger, the initial table is 10 cells wide, 20 high and might contain empty rows.  Hope there is a work around.

Also, it only breaks when the zero(0) is directly after the dash (-); '-y0y' works for example.

Worst case I can edit the intial output column to add an extra '-' whenever a '0' is encountered; but I'd rather not.

Minor edit: in '_Condition' changed it to 9 instead of 10.

Comment: Have you tried to debug, found it is giving `CALC!` error from step `_unicon`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya well I copied it from your previous response, with only a small change to the '_uniday' part; maybe you still have the previous file? (if you saved it back then)

Comment: Wait I have to find the file where I have saved it.

Comment: You need to make changes here: `--LEFT(TEXTAFTER(_databody," "))` instead of `TEXTAFTER()` make it `TEXTBEFORE()` and here is the [Excel](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ck1axuzuGTFpi6KSB?e=bc8j7Z)

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya thanks, this seems to work! Do you have any idea why it fails with TEXTAFTER() though?

Comment: Excellor, it was because not detecting the delimiter empty and dash/hyphen and returning all as text and not numbers. also I am not posting it as an answer since its a duplicate. Hope that is ok with you! Let me know.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I'm fine with that, thanks for the help and the explanation!

Comment: Thank you. That is why I use variables with underscores in the front. it makes easier to read, if you use them one by one to debug then it will help to understand as well

Comment: I'm impressed by your formula, but would a UDF not be a better solution? It's far better debuggable, and if ever you need to modify it within a year or even later, you won't have the smallest idea how this formula actually works.

Comment: It depends on perspective, it varies from people to people. One who knows both can debug one who knows one will go either of the one. So what said it goes for others also one who doesn't know programming they may also face the same problem.